# VSCode - PHP - Update namespace and imports of other files after moving class

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure VSCode to have the following occur after moving a file to another locations?

- Update the namespace of the class/trait.
- Update the imports of all other files referencing this file.

For example, let's say I have the following classes in `src/app`:

`src/app/Hello.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

class Hello {
...
}
```

`src/app/Goodbye.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Hello;

class Goodbye {
...
}
```

I want to move my `src/app/Hello.php` file into `src/app/services/Hello.php`. The following should occur:

- The namespace changes from `namespace App` to `namespace App\Services`
- The import in `src/app/Goodbye.php` changes from `use App\Hello` to `use App\Services\Hello`

So then we will have:
`src/app/services/Hello.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class Hello {
...
}
```

`src/app/Goodbye.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Services\Hello;

class Goodbye {
...
}
```

Can this be done with the PHP Intelephense or PHP Namespace Resolver extension, or by any other means?